# Foreman: Pass host comment to puppet

Tags: puppet, foreman, puppet-foreman

In the Foreman there is the ability to set a comment for hosts. I would like to pass this comment to a puppet class assigned to these hosts so that the comment can be printed in the motd of the hosts. Is there a way in which I can pass the comment from Foreman to Puppet?

Comment: Yes, OK. But the information I want is already in the comment. Is there no way but to duplicate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be accessible as `$::comment`.

You can see a list of parameters passed through to Puppet from Foreman's ENC interface by clicking the *YAML* button on a host page:

```
parameters:
  domainname: example.com
  hostgroup: My host group
  comment: Example comment added under the host.
```

All of the parameters there are global, so are in Puppet's top-scope, accessible as `$::example`.